# Executing Long Running SQL from MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, sqlcommand

I am looking to implement a process to call a long running sql SPROC (it populates lots of data into some tables) using MSBuild. I have the following code to call the SPROC from my build server

```
    <Target Name="Test"  AfterTargets="Deploy">
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.SqlServer.SqlExecute TaskAction="ExecuteRawReader" Sql="DECLARE  @return_value int, @Result nvarchar(1000) EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[usp_ProcessWarehouse] @Result = @Result OUTPUT SELECT    @Result as N'@Result' SELECT    'Return Value' = @return_value"
        ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ETL;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=10000">
        <Output PropertyName="RawResult" TaskParameter="RawReaderResult"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.SqlServer.SqlExecute>
    <Message Text="$(RawResult)"/>
</Target>
```

The SPROC is as follows

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ProcessWarehouse]
   @Result Nvarchar(1000) OUTPUT
AS
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'MB_ProcessWarehouse'
WaitFor Delay '00:00:05'
Declare @cnt int = 0
WHILE (@cnt <> 5)
BEGIN    
   set @cnt =   (
                 SELECT count(*)
                 FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity AS sja
                 INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS sj ON sja.job_id = sj.job_id
                 WHERE sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
                 AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL)
                 if @cnt = 0
                 Begin
                 set  @cnt = 5
                 Break
                 End
                 Print 'Job Still Running'
                 WaitFor Delay '00:00:05'
END
Print 'Job Completed'

Set @result = (
               SELECT top 1
               CASE jh.run_status WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
               WHEN 1 THEN 'Success'
               WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
               WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
               WHEN 4 THEN 'In progress'
               END AS Status
               FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
               INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh 
               ON jh.job_id = j.job_id AND jh.step_id = 0 
               inner join msdb.dbo.syscategories sc
               on j.category_id = sc.category_id
               WHERE j.[name] like 'MB_ProcessWarehouse'
               order by jh.run_date desc, jh.run_time desc
               )
```

So basically what this SPROC does is run some SQL to kick off the job, then check to see when it completes and checks the status of it. The job can take up 30 minutes to complete.

The actual target gets called and kicks off the job, however the msbuild task fails with this error

```
SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding
```

I have tried a few things, like changing the timeout for SQL in the registry, but I still get this error after 60 seconds. Is there a way for me to get around this? Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do. I want to kick off this SPROC as part of the Build Process, after a Deploy to populate data in lower environments.

Comment: Perhaps try another task, or write your own for testing with an inline task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ConnectionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) is not relevant here, you're looking for [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx), the [task property](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.9.0/html/e2ec6733-ca26-a7cc-e1cb-1edd43f7d79d.htm).

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="SqlExecute" AssemblyFile="C:\Users\Ilya.Kozhevnikov\Dropbox\MSBuildExtensionPack\Solutions\Main\BuildBinaries\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll" />

    <Target Name="Foo">
        <SqlExecute
            TaskAction="ExecuteRawReader"
            Sql="WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:31'"
            ConnectionString="Integrated Security=true"
            CommandTimeout="32"
        />
    </Target>
</Project>
```